# Alternative to SOAP?

Tags: web-services

I've read somewhere that there is a lightweight and simpler webservice alternative to SOAP. Now I cant find it again.
In the exapmle I saw, I think it was used in Android to call services on App Engine.

Does anybody know about this?

Comment: I think you are talking about `REST`

Comment: I don't mean REST. I should have mentioned that. It is a protocol to do Remote Procedure Calls. Exactly as webservices is used, just another implementation and another protocol.

Comment: @Erik, is it `Atom protocol` OR `Cisco's Etch`? I searched google and found them

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, there are quite a few to choose from.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_web_service_protocols

But it sounds like maybe you mean JSON RPC?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON-RPC

Comment: The list on Wikipedia helped me. I was looking for Hessian! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's called REST.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/REST

Answer (score 0):

I think you are talking about `Representational State Transfer OR REST`. REST is a lightweight alternative to mechanisms like RPC (Remote Procedure Calls) and Web Services

See here

[REST](http://rest.elkstein.org/)

**EDIT:**

Are you then referring to `Atom protocol` OR CISCO's `Etch`. I searched Google and found them

Answer (score 0):

Depends what you're trying to do, but ultimately, HTTP is usually all you need.

do an HTTP POST request to http://example.com/my/resource and you've created new resource that will be available at http://example.com/my/resource/[id]. Do an HTTP PUT on http://example.com/my/resource/[id] and you've updated that resource.

Everybody generally refers to this as a "RESTful" web service, but really, it's just using HTTP in a much purer way, and, since it's pure HTTP, the content type can be of your choosing for representing the data you want to store and retrieve.

There are frameworks for many languages that make defining the end points of your webservice painfully easy as well. JAVA has Jersey, PHP has Glue and Python has Flask for example.

Comment: You are right that "REST" is just "pure HTTP" but your comment shows that you really do not understand what REST is and why it is not just "only pure http". It works over pure http, but it does not mean it is just that.